# Perforce: Additional edits after resolve

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I've performed integration (`p4 integrate`) and then resolved conflicts in all files (`p4 resolve ...`). After that I noticed that one conflict could be resolved better by providing additional edits.

I want Perforce to think that the additional edits (after `p4 edit file/in/question` and `vim file/in/question`) are part of resolution, not an separate edit.

How can achieve this using `p4` command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `p4 edit` and make the edits, they will be part of the same atomic changelist and the same revision.

(It is possible to make the edits in such a way as to have them not get propagated back to the source on a reverse integrate, by "hiding" them in the merge, but you probably don't want to do this because it likely means you'll end up re-resolving the conflict later.)

Comment: What I meant is that after additional `p4 edit`, when I issue `p4 describe -s CHANGE` I get `document.txt#61 edit` instead `document.txt#61 integrate`. I would prefer for Perforce  server to treat additional edit after accepting `p4 resolve` as part of integration, not separate edit.

Comment: By "treat" do you mean literally just the string "edit" vs "integrate" or is there other behavior that you're trying to get/avoid?

Comment: You can change the action by doing `resolve -f` and then editing the merge, but that also means you're re-running the merge, so depending on how you resolved other conflicts previously you might end up having to redo some work, which is why I'd recommend `p4 edit` -- there's not a significant difference between an edited merge and an edit with a merge and the edit is a simpler workflow.

Comment: I'm accepting, because it seems that there is no way to do what I want - thanks @Sam Stafford. Some more words on what was on my mind: I had several _bad_ integrations resolved with `-as`, `-a` incorrectly. I _assumed_ that Perforce, internally, is treating `edit` and `integrate` differently and future integrations of the same patch might (a) go wrong again if this is treated as `edit` or (b) Perforce won't show proper results when asked about `interchanges`. I hope that my _assumption_ is incorrect.

Comment: If you post on forums.perforce.com with more details about these bad integrations and what you're concerned about I can probably talk you through it with diagrams and stuff (source: I wrote Perforce's current integrate algorithm).  :)

Comment: e.g. it's not clear to me whether you're talking about bad integrations that were already submitted, or that were part of this same revision, and it's also not clear what you consider to be "proper" results from interchanges or which direction you're querying in.  Having a more concrete example would be necessary.  As a general rule though it's better to do the more straightforward thing (i.e. in this case `p4 edit`) rather than trying to do something more complicated like "fake" integration records.

Comment: Can you add the `p4 resolve -f file/in/question` comment as an option to the answer please?

Comment: `resolve -f` isn't a good answer to the question in the OP because it will re-run the merge algorithm with different inputs, and if you don't know what's going on it's easy to inadvertently lose changes.  If you just want to add an edit, you want to use `p4 edit`.